# Delay in keyboard input, caused by mouse

Tags: input, uwp, windows-10-universal, keyboard-events, monogame

In my UWP MonoGame app, all keystrokes are delayed by mouse input. It has two effects:

1) When holding any key, the input continues after I physically release. This ends when I stop moving the mouse around quickly.

2) When I press a key, while moving the mouse around quickly, the input is not received until I stop moving the mouse around.

This is event that is firing late.

```
window.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
```

Comment: It's difficult without the code, but I found this: Apps do not receive this event when an Input Method Editor (IME) is enabled. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown or look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421867/how-do-i-handle-keydown-event-in-winrt-app-xaml-and-c-which-has-a-webview

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the input events getting backlogged, due to the Windows::UI::Core::CoreProcessEventsOption flag passed to ProcessEvents. Rapid mouse input will fill the event queue faster than they are being processed, and when the queue becomes full the new events will be discarded.

```
coreWindow->Dispatcher->ProcessEvents(Windows::UI::Core::CoreProcessEventsOption::ProcessOneIfPresent);
```

Pass a more appropriate flag for realtime input, such as ProcessAllIfPresent.